# How do I refresh a ListItem or reload it from an URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

**Problem:** In the `foreach` below, I have 2 parts.

Part 1 opens an excel File and modifies it
Part 2 updates 3 of the `ListItem` fields

Both parts work individually but with them both enabled, Part 2 fails do to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Version conflict.'` understandably

**Question:** How can I refresh/reload my ListItem between Part 1 and Part 2?

I tried `ListItem.RefreshLoad();`
And I looked all over for something along the lines of `ListItem.GetFromURL();` but can't seem to find what I'm looking for

```
            ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(site)
            SecureString pass = new SecureString();
            Web web = cc.Web;

            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray())
            {
                pass.AppendChar(c);
            }

            cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("User@Domain.com", pass);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");

            CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>"
            };
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(qry);

            cc.Load(listItems);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {

                //PART 1
                //Open the file
                //Modify the File
                //Save the file

                //PART 2
                listItem["Updated"] = DateTime.Now;
                listItem["Update_x0020_Duration"] = totalTime;
                listItem["System_x0020_Comment"] = "TestComment";
                listItem.Update();
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Immediately after the modification (Update()) in part 1, do a cc.Load(listItem), BEFORE your cc.ExecuteQuery() that concludes part 1. So logically you’re saying to the server, “modify the file and then refresh my local file object so I can proceed with using it”. Otherwise you’re working with a stale version of it in part 2.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace can be a bit tricky.
 I have struggled with the same issue in the past.
This is the general idea based on your code. please read comments:

```
    ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(site);
    // try to use the List object, using the name of the list as the parameter
    List oList = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    // pass the credantials!
    cc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(< username >, < password >, < domain >);
    // another option - default NetworkCredentials credantials
    // context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    // pass the uniq id of the record
    ListItem listItem = oList.GetItemById(id);
    // now you can to this
    // ...............
    listItem["System_x0020_Comment"] = "TestComment";
    listItem.Update();
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already have this part working. If I use Part 1 in my code it saves the file , effectively changing the list item. I need to refresh the ListItem with the new item so I can change the data of the list item.